# laravel query problem using join, what is missing?

Tags: php, laravel

first of all Im not good at english and im new using laravel framework. Im developing some school site for thesis purposes. And I think this might be a chance for me to learn laravel since many developers recommends laravel.

back to my problem hehe

This query runs right.

```
$questions = DB::table('questions')
                            ->select('questions.id','questions.role','questions.postBody', 'questions.classCode', 'questions.postedById', 'questions.created_at', 'classroom.classroomName','classroom.icon','users.picture', 'students.firstName', 'students.middleName', 'students.lastName', 'students.suffix','students.studentNumber')
                            ->join('classroom', 'classroom.classCode', '=', 'questions.classCode')
                            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'questions.postedById')
                            ->join('students', 'students.email' , '=', 'users.email')
                            ->orderBy('questions.created_at', 'DESC')
                            ->skip($request->page - 5)
                            ->take($request->page)
                            ->get();
```

and when I adding other table ("teacher") i got no returns. This is the example of my query trying to join 'teacher' table and in here, im trying to select email of teacher

```
 $questions = DB::table('questions')
                            ->select('questions.id','questions.role','questions.postBody', 'questions.classCode', 'questions.postedById', 'questions.created_at', 'classroom.classroomName','classroom.icon','users.picture', 'students.firstName', 'students.middleName', 'students.lastName', 'students.suffix','students.studentNumber','teacher.email')
                            ->join('classroom', 'classroom.classCode', '=', 'questions.classCode')
                            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'questions.postedById')
                            ->join('students', 'students.email' , '=', 'users.email')
                            ->join('teacher', 'teacher.email' , '=', 'users.email')
                            ->orderBy('questions.created_at', 'DESC')
                            ->skip($request->page - 5)
                            ->take($request->page)
                            ->get();
```

sorry for my bad english.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: are you sure the table's name is `teacher` and not  `teachers`?

Comment: @Aless55, Yes im sure.

Comment: is it possible that there are no results of the inner join? are you sure that there are is a user email that is also a teacher email?

Comment: are you sure you want to use inner join instead of left join?

Comment: @Aless55, if im gonna use left join. How can I select fields from it. It is same method as join? can you give me example please?

Comment: check my answer below :) @user10182078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after your first inner join there are only useres left that are also students. Because inner join is taking the cut-set of the joined tables:
[image]

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

In the next innerjoin you are trying to get the cut-set of email addresses that are in the students and also teacher table. This will probably always be empty.
I recommend that you look up DB joins and I would use `leftJoin` for your use case.

```
->leftJoin('students', 'students.email' , '=', 'users.email')
->leftJoin('teacher', 'teacher.email' , '=', 'users.email')
```

Here are some good answers on the topic:
[What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: ohhh that makes sense. But can you tell me too how to select that email from different table?

Comment: the select should work like in your code teacher.email or what do you want to select?

Comment: for example i want to select their both email. Is that possible?

Comment: I just tried the whole answers i found.I also select firstname, middlename and lastname in teacher table. And yes, it did select teachers table. But for some reason firstname middlename and lastname of student table becomes null when i getting the returns. It seems to confuse cuz both table have the same fields name such as firstname, lastname, middlename and even email

Comment: or should I change fields name that teachers have?

Comment: no you could do a `selectRaw('teacher.firstname as teacher_firstname, techer.lastname as teacher_lastname')` isntead of the select, where you rename the attributes with the `as`.

Comment: Thank you very very very much!!!! It works perfectly. Good thing you notice my question!